# vscode chrome attach unable to connect after some time

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a really wired problem (or a bug) on vscode. I can "attach chrome" debugging totally fine usually,

but after some random time connecting to the chrome instance (may be a couple of hours or 8 hours, like I left it connected while I'm sleeping), it automatically disconnect the debugging,

then when I try to re-run attach chrome to reconnect it, for some weird reason it doesn't connect to the instance.

It's not a failed, it's not like "cannot connect to the port 9222", it's infinitely trying to connect showing the left up side blue indicator left to right.

This is my second time to encounter this weird problem. For the first time I even don't know how I solved the issue. maybe I just waited its reconnect for an hour or like that.

The first things I happened to think from the problem is simply its port conflict. So I checked vscode side's (I mean I use vscode in the remote ssh mode from Windows to Linux Ubuntu) port and process, used htop to filter port "9222" or process "chrome", but I didn't find anything stucking there. So I assume in the linux side the debugging process is exiting successfully.

So I did the same on the Windows side, I used resource monitor to check port "9222", no running process. If I re-open a 9222 debugging enable chrome, then it appears. closing, it disappears. It seems there is no problem here as well.

I then checked vscode's version. I was using vscode 1.64.2 so I side-installed 1.65.2 and 1.66.1 (the latest) and tested it. Doesn't work.

"refreshing the window" doesn't work. closing the window and re-open, doesn't work.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just install some new extensions in Visual Studio Code? I found that I had this exact same behaviour, "infinitely trying to connect showing the left up side blue indicator left to right", after I installed Karma Test Explorer and Test Explorer UI extensions. Once I uninstalled those extensions, debugging started working again.

Comment: Hi. Not really. don't have any suspicious extensions. I think the only way to solve the problem (for me at least) is either or both 1. closing/killing all vscode instances, then restart 2. rebooting the machine 3. just wait. may be 30 minutes, may be 4 hours;